# .Net RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardInput are overlapping

Tags: c#, stream, stdout, stdin

I am writing a prototype application that will require redirecting the stdin and stdout streams of a command-line application to a different application, and it kind of works. However, there is some annoying behavior which I cannot seem to work around. Anything written to the StandardInput stream also appears in the StandardOutput stream.

Using command prompt as an example, I would write, the following into the StandardInput stream:

```
C:\Users\Me>echo Hello
```

and then on StandardOutput, I read the following:

```
echo Hello
Hello
```

For more examples:

```
C:\Users\Me>ls
ls
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
C:\Users\Me>whoami
whoami
domain\Me
C:\Users\Me>NonSensicalCommand fooArgs fooArg1 forArg2 ImAlittleTeapot
NonSensicalCommand fooArgs fooArg1 forArg2 ImAlittleTeapot 
'NonSensicalCommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This seems to be universal, to any application where I redirect the streams. I have tried with cmd, Plink, and some personal CLI items I've written. Anything and everything written to StandardInput always shows up in StandardOutput.

Is there something I can do which would keep these two streams separate? I've tried starting with things like "echo off", but that doesn't accomplish anything.

The following is my code (again, using cmd as an example; to run with plink, swap the PSI lines)

```C#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

static void Main( string[ ] args )
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" );

    // If you'd like to run the code with the Plink, use the below line instead
    //ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink" ,
    //"-ssh someUser@SshServer.SomeDomain.com -pw FooPass" );

    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = false;

    Process process = new Process( );
    process.StartInfo = psi;
    process.Exited += Process_Exited;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start( );
    process.StandardInput.NewLine = "\n"; // using \r\n causes confusion in the Unix environment; just use \n
    process.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;

    // [Lines 30 -> 42] Async Routine constantly reads stdout and prints to screen; reads a sinlge byte, then reads again.
    AsyncCallback stdOutCallback = null;
    byte[ ] myBuffer = new byte[1];

    stdOutCallback = asyResult =>
    {
        int bytesRead = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead( asyResult );

        Console.Write( Encoding.ASCII.GetString( myBuffer ) );

        process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead( myBuffer, 0, 1, stdOutCallback, null );
    };
    
    process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead( myBuffer, 0, 1, stdOutCallback, null );
    
    
    // Writing to StandardInput exists inside a dedicated thread which will be handed the process
    new Thread( WriteToInput ).Start( process );
    
    // Wait for controlled process to exit
    process.WaitForExit( );
}

// Raisable event; current application exits with the same exit code as connected process
static void Process_Exited( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Environment.Exit( ((Process)sender).ExitCode );
}

// Constant loop which reads console input and writes it to connected process StandardInput
static void WriteToInput( object targ )
{
    Process process = (Process)targ;
    
    string input = Console.ReadLine( );
    
    while ( input != "---" )
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine( input );
        input = Console.ReadLine( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your issue, but consider using [`Envrionment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-6.0) for `process.StandardInput.NewLine`. It will ensure you have the correct value for the given OS.

Comment: We're standardizing it to just be "\n". We were originally using `Environment.NewLine`, but when the application ran on windows and communicated with a Unix ssh server (like in the Plink example), NewLine caused some weird behavior where it counted as 2 line completion characters being sent to the input stream.

I do appreciate the input though!